# Como ordenar colunas do sql no alter table

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma alteração para fazer na tabela `Inclusão de colunas` a duvida é tem como eu definir a ordem quando estou fazendo a alteração no sql server 2008 ?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Arquivos 
ADD IdTipoDocumento int NULL, -- order 3
    NomeInterno nvarchar(200) NULL, -- order 4
    DirArquivo nvarchar(200) NULL,-- order 5
    DescrArquivo nvarchar(max) NULL, -- order 6
    LarguraArquivo int NULL, -- order 12
    AlturaArquivo int NULL, --  order 13
    FlagAtivo bit NULL, -- order 14
    IdUsuarioUpload int NULL, -- order 15
    DtInclusao datetime NULL -- order 16
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não faço ideia se tenha como fazer isso, mas uma maneira seria você criar uma tabela temporária e recriar sua tabela na ordem correta, e fazer o insert dos registros da tabela dbo.arquivos na temporária, algo assim.

Comment: sei como funciona... mas dar um trabalho, achava que teria algo mais fácil...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, [apenas pelo SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337556.aspx). Pelo Transact-SQL isto não é possível.

Pro banco de dados, a ordem das colunas é irrelevante. Essa funcionalidade pode ser considerada até cosmética, visto que não afeta em nada o desempenho ou o funcionamento da tabela.

Comment: talvez seja interessante mencionar que o management Studio irá recriar a tabela e caso alguma coisa dê errado, a tabela pode acaba no limbo ou corrompida.

Comment: Caramba. Sério isso? Só preciso da fonte.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Sim, em termo de desempenho não afeta mesmo, era algo mais apresentável para minha aplicação mesmo. Só não sabia se tinha algo que fizesse isso no próprio `alter table`. Vlw.

Comment: hauhauha eu ia falar para criar uma tabela virtual, exportar pra ela os dados, dar um drop da tabela e recriar ela, depois inserir os dados da tabela virtual ;P deve ser isso que o management faz hauauha

Comment: @Rod é possível sim fazer dessa forma, mas é um pouco trabalhoso. O que o SQL Server Management Studio faz por traz para ordenar... só falando com o Bill Gates

Comment: @Rod, é justamente isto que o `Management Studio`, você pode verificar isto, abrindo o Design para uma tabela, re-ordenando as colunas e ao invés de salvar a alteração use a opção para `Gerar Script de Alteração`, ele vai lhe entregar um script que cria uma tabela temporaria, copia os dados para esta tabela, apaga a anterior junto com os relacionamentos e renomeia a temporaria e recria os relacionamentos.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, esperimente fazer o seguinte: `Ferramentas` -> `Opções` -> `Designers`, então marque a opção `Evitar salvar alterações que exijam recriação de tabela`... Se fizer isto, você não vai conseguir salvar alterações no Design da tabela como alterar a ordem das colunas, tornar um tipo NULL em NOT NULL, etc... Se fizer isto e tentar salvar, o `Management Studio` irá lhe informar que não pode prosseguir.

Comment: @TobyMosque Dica sensacional. Não vou nem complementar a resposta para te dar o devido crédito.